# How to prevent pandas.read_gbq infer data types of columns

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

- I am reading a table from google bigquery using `pandas.read_gbq`. The issue I am facing is `pandas` automatically infer data types of each column and this is creating issue.
- For example in table I have a column name `aspect_ratio` and pandas automatically convert all values to floats which i want to prevent.

```
source        df          expected
55            55.0        55
25            25.0        25
21            21.0        21
nan           nan         nan
22            22.0        22
22.5          22.5        22.5
```

- I need exact representation here without floating point. **I want string representation of source column.**
- I have tried following solution but it will not work.

```
df['col'].astype(str) # this will just change 55.0 to '55.0' 
df['col'].astype(int) # this will also wont work since it will raise error for 22.5
```

- I have checked [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_gbq.html) for `pandas.read_gbq` but am unable to find anything that can help in this case.
- I would also like to know about any other options I can use in python, not just limited to `pandas`.

Comment: @Ben.T I have updated the question hope its more clear now and you see why astype('Int') or astype('str') kind of solution wont work.

Comment: after looking at the documentation, it doesn't look like there is anything you can do specifically with regards to `read_gbq`.  My recommendation is to just convert it to string, then do another transformation that trims the string if `s[-2:] == '.0'`

Comment: @rtenha That hack will fail for case `22.5`. Which should be `22.5` not `22.0` .

Comment: what do you mean?  it would only modify the string if the last 2 characters of the string are `.0`, which would be false for `22.5`

Answer (score 0):

Are the original values in BigQuery table strings?  It seems surprising that pandas-GBQ would do this conversion if they were.

If the values are originally strings you might try using the official [BigQuery storage API adapter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-storage-python-pandas) which might have different results.

If this is just a display issue you could use a custom Pandas formatter:

```
def format(f):
    if f % 1 == 0:
        return repr(int(f))
    return repr(f)
# should be able to set this locally as well.
pd.options.display.float_format = format 
pd.DataFrame([[.5], [-5.0], [22.5]], columns=['a'])
```

Yields:

```
     a
0  0.5
1   -5
2 22.5
```